# How to only allow users of a specific country to access my django website?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am building a website powered by django to serve a particular country only. Then, how can i redirect traffic from all other countries to an specific error page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return `403` headers based on IP ranges that belong to a particular country, or you can just use this [library](https://django-iprestrict.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that will do just that, you can select a particular IP or a whole country .

```
from netaddr import IPNetwork, IPAddress

def get_client_ip(request):
    forbiden_ip_subnets = [...list of forbidden ip subnets...]
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    ip = 0
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    for ip_sub in forbiden_ip_subnets:
        if IPAddress(ip) in IPNetwork(ip_sub):
            from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always configure your application depending on your needs using the [Django Forbid](https://pypi.org/project/django-forbid/). Using this library, you can declare countries allowlist as well as handle specific error pages. See the official [docs](https://docs.pysnippet.org/django-forbid/) for setup and configuration.